# Webpage slow to load ajax query took too long to retrieve despite index

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, .htaccess, caching, playframework-1.x

So I have this web page that contain literally all rows in a table.
This table only have atm at most say a thousand rows. Anyways, it took the whole page at least 7-8 seconds to load, and it's unacceptable.

My current solution is either:

1) Cache the table on server side using play framework cache.

2) Cache table on client side by putting the table in separate html page, use htaccess, and load it on iframe.

3) Partially or don't load the table until user asks for it. From what i see, most of our users use the search bar to filter the table anyway, so what's the point of loading the whole table. But then again i can't speak for everyone.

I'm using play framework 1 and hibernate.

I've tried rewriting the query by selecting just the required fields rather than returning all fields (hibernate.findAll), but that doesn't seem to improve the load time.

I've used the play cache, load time was halved, but i read some forum entries that are against caching saying they're hard to manage.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You say that "web page load" is slow. But assuming that problem is in DB. Have you walked through entire system flow before such conclusion? I mean, "web page load" is determine from various variables like: a) http requests done between browser/web; b) web page html/css/js code rendering; c) requests/connections done between client/server; d) network latency... etc.
Also if you are 100% certain the problem is in DB then please provide EXPLAIN ANALYZE result of your query.

Comment: the page spent literally few ms to load resources - like really really short. The page have some other details in them, and they loaded in few ms as well. When I go to the network analysis of the page, it took 8 seconds to completely load the table. I have not used EXPLAIN ANALYZE just yet, but since it's retrieving the whole table, I'm guessing it's just doing full table scan. But i'll double check tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The time spent loading needs to be broken into its composite pieces. If you are concerned about the query speed and index usage, you will want to determine the raw query being executed. Then, you can use an **explain analyze** command to determine what is actually happening.